# Best practice for accessing variables from a do-catch block

Tags: swift, scope, do-catch

A standard do-catch block looks like this in Swift:

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
  let file = try jsonEncoder.encode(pets)
} catch {
  return
}
// want to access file here
```

My question is what is the best practice for accessing the variable created inside the do-catch block? My instinct says to first create the variable outside the block as a unwrapped optional (`let file: Data!`) but it doesn't feel very elegant. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply declare `file` outside the scope of the `do-catch` block and then access it after the the `do-catch` block. This works, because you are returning from the `catch` block, so you can never reach the `print` statement without `file` being initialised - it either gets a value from the `do` block or the function returns from the `catch` block, in which case the `print` is never executed.

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let file: Data
do {
    file = try jsonEncoder.encode(pets)
} catch {
    return
}
// Do whatever you need with file
print(file)
```

Comment: `guard` + `try?` would be an alternative.

Comment: In this case we will get the compiler error: "Variable 'file' used before being initialized".